# Same type of dataset, one works, anotherone generates error: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, bert-language-model

```
def fast_encode(texts, tokenizer, chunk_size=256, maxlen=128):

    tokenizer.enable_truncation(max_length=maxlen)
    tokenizer.enable_padding()
    all_ids = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(texts), chunk_size):
        text_chunk = texts[i:i+chunk_size].tolist()
        encs = tokenizer.encode_batch(text_chunk)
        all_ids.extend([enc.ids for enc in encs])
    return np.array(all_ids)
```

The following works perfectly:

```
x_train = toxic_df['clean1']
x_dev = dev_df['clean1']
x_test = test_df['clean1']

x_train = fast_encode(x_train.values, fast_tokenizer)
x_dev = fast_encode(x_dev.values, fast_tokenizer)
x_test = fast_encode(x_test.values, fast_tokenizer)

print(type(toxic_df['clean1']))
print(type(toxic_df['clean1'][1]))
print(type(x_train))
print(type(x_train[0]))
print(type(x_train[0][1]))
print(x_train.shape)
```

Corresponding datatype:

```
print(type(toxic_df['clean1']))
print(type(toxic_df['clean1'][1]))
print(type(x_train))
print(type(x_train[0]))
print(type(x_train[0][1]))
print(x_train.shape)
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
(30588, 128)
```

Out put of x_train:

```
array([[  101,  1045,  5223, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [  101,  1036,  1036, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [  101,  1027,  6775, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       ...,
       [  101,  1036,  1036, ...,  2003,  1996,   102],
       [  101,  2008, 11669, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [  101,  1037,  5227, ...,     0,     0,     0]])
```

But the next one has the error of : Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

```
x_train1 = train_sentences['line']
x_dev1 = dev_sentences['line']
x_test1 = test_sentences['line']

x_train1 = fast_encode(x_train1.values, fast_tokenizer)
x_dev1 = fast_encode(x_dev1.values, fast_tokenizer)
x_test1 = fast_encode(x_test1.values, fast_tokenizer)
```

```
print(type( train_sentences['line']))
print(type( train_sentences['line'][1]))
print(type(x_train1))
print(type(x_train1[0]))
print(type(x_train1[0][1]))
print(x_train1.shape)
```

The corresponding datatypes:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'int'>
(241138,)
```

Out put of x_train1:

```
array([list([101, 2187, 2026, 4845, 1999, 1996, 2082, 1998, 4741, 1999, 1996, 5581, 2843, 2000, 12665, 2032, 1024, 1022, 2095, 2214, 4845, 1012, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
       list([101, 5292, 6687, 3836, 3034, 1012, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
       list([101, 3188, 1996, 1996, 3034, 2002, 2003, 13847, 2041, 2055, 2242, 1006, 2000, 2026, 2564, 2096, 1045, 2572, 2025, 2045, 1007, 1012, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
       ...,
       list([101, 1036, 1036, 1027, 1027, 11721, 3319, 1027, 1027, 1024, 2023, 3319, 2003, 9099, 20464, 13936, 2013, 2831, 1024, 2250, 2634, 4671, 3462, 6282, 2475, 1013, 11721, 2487, 1012, 1996, 10086, 4957, 2005, 2023, 2930, 2064, 2022, 2109, 2000, 5587, 7615, 2000, 1996, 3319, 1012, 12027, 1024, 1036, 1036, 1005, 1005, 2029, 2012, 2105, 5757, 1024, 2382, 2334, 2051, 2006, 2570, 2089, 2230, 1010, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1011, 2017, 2323, 3602, 2029, 2051, 4224, 2009, 2003, 7727, 2000, 2043, 2009, 2360, 1036, 1036, 1005, 1005, 2334, 2051, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1010, 2030, 2488, 2664, 1010, 2074, 2404, 1996, 2051, 1999, 11396, 1012, 2070, 4431, 2024, 1999, 1996, 3308, 2173, 1010, 2138, 2009, 2298, 2066, 2070, 4861, 2024, 4895, 6499, 3126, 11788, 1012, 2023, 2003, 1996, 102]),
       list([101, 2008, 11669, 2100, 2771, 15714, 19771, 2318, 2000, 7065, 8743, 2026, 2219, 2147, 1998, 2404, 5762, 11669, 2100, 4471, 2006, 2026, 2219, 2686, 1012, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
       list([101, 1037, 5227, 7592, 4557, 8040, 8747, 7520, 1010, 2115, 7953, 1999, 7367, 22895, 2100, 3720, 11333, 2200, 14044, 1012, 2017, 2156, 2714, 3663, 4158, 1998, 1999, 2023, 3720, 1010, 2007, 1996, 2168, 3218, 1997, 18558, 28649, 8208, 1012, 4385, 1012, 2071, 2017, 3531, 2156, 1996, 6594, 2182, 1998, 3073, 2115, 7615, 2006, 2023, 3277, 1029, 1045, 2052, 2022, 2200, 8794, 2000, 2017, 1012, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])],
      dtype=object)
```

It is obvious they are different, and I have been trying to solve it for a long while, I tried most of the solution that is listed online already, but none of them work, I am not sure if I miss anything, so any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

What can I do to make the result of x_train1 have the same format/datatype as x_train? Thank you!!

Comment: Try `np.stack(x_train1)`

Comment: `I tried most of the solution that is listed online already, but none of them work` - that's a most unsatisfactory description of your efforts.  How do you know we won't suggest some of the same fixes?  Wouldn't that just be a waste of our time, and yours?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help!! Secondly, I mentioned that it is because I did try most of the methods, and I want to mention that so that people would know the common solution may not work since I tried most of them. I did also notice that most of the solution is pretty similar so I mentioned that just avoid redundancy. Again, Thank you for your help!!!!!